# Not receiving emails on form submit

Tags: php, html, web-development-server

I have designed an email for a cart page in [this  website](https://onlineooty.co.in). When checkout is clicked nothing happens. Instead it displays an empty page with a different header.

PHP:

```php
<?php
  $subject = "An order has been placed on your website";

if (isset($_POST['button '])) {
  $firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
  $lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
  $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $productName = $_POST['product-name'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
  $phone = $_POST['tel'];

  $mailTo = "admin@onlineooty.co.in";
  $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
  $txt = "you have recieved a mail from ".$firstName.".\n\n"."whose address is  : ".$address.".\n\n"."the product name is: ".$productName."\n\n"."the phone number is: ".$phone;

  mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers );
  header("Location: cart.php?mailsend");
}
?>
```

My form:

```html
<form class="emailForm" action="email.php" method="post">
  <div class="input-checkbox">
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="product-name" placeholder=" product required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity in kgs" max="10">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="pin-code" placeholder="Pin Code">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="input" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="phone">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="payment-method">
  <span>Kindly proceed with the payment to get order confirmation <font color="red">*No refund provided after order confirmation*</font></span>
  <div class="input-radio">
    <label for="payment-2">
    <span>We do accept payments only on Google Pay as of now.
    </span>
    Google Pay
    </label>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>We do accept payments on <font color = "blue">GPay
        </font>, you can pay us on this number <strong>123456789
        </strong>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="submit-button" type="submit" name="button">Checkout
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the space that comes after button between the single quotes 'button ' in your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space, your code should be like this:

```
<?php
  $subject = "An order has been placed on your website";

if (isset($_POST['button'])){
  $firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
  $lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
  $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $productName = $_POST['product-name'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
  $phone = $_POST['tel'];

  $mailTo = "admin@onlineooty.co.in";
  $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
  $txt = "you have recieved a mail from ".$firstName.".\n\n"."whose address is  : ".$address.".\n\n"."the product name is: ".$productName."\n\n"."the phone number is: ".$phone;

  mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers );
  header("Location: cart.php?mailsend");

}
```

Comment: this is my first php code, u sure the code is correct ??

Comment: I think you can run and check, it is correct or not.